# Blank label_suffix across entire Django project

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'd like to eliminate the colon (:) that is automatically added to form labels across my entire Django project. I'd like to avoid adding `label_suffix=''` to every form in the project.

Is there a simple way to override it everywhere?

Comment: feature request: https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/issues/130

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would probably be best to extend Django's `Form` class, override the default, and extend all of your forms from it, like so:

```
from django import forms

class MySiteForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(MySiteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

...

class RegistrationForm(MySiteForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

Comment: Where is the best place to do this?

Comment: @Brenden I usually keep a forms.py file in an app and then import any needed forms into my views, like: `from myapp.forms import RegistrationForm`

Comment: Should `kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')`  after super?

Comment: I'm trying this in a FormLabelSuffixMixin. I'll also do a getattr(self, 'label_suffix', '') to allow it to be defined more declaratively on a form class. The default behaviour is disappointing IMHO.

Comment: Philip007, the kwargs dict must be modified before the super(MySiteForm, self).__init__ call, as it's used in the call itself. Nothing would happen if it occurred after the call; the label_suffix keyword argument would not be overridden.

Comment: Backwards incompatible changes in 1.6; BoundField.label_tag now includes the form’s label_suffix https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/#boundfield-label-tag-now-includes-the-form-s-label-suffix